# "Regular" Ruby gem or Rails engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rubygems, dry

My Rails apps (compilation of Rails 3 and 4) all have their own database (naturally), but also access a 3rd-party database.  As such, they have models to this 3rd-party database.  I want to DRY up these models to be reusable instead of copy-pasting them in each app.  There are no controllers, helpers, or routes to consider; only models.  But since it has Rails "parts", this would seem to indicate I need an engine.  But the fact that I want these models in all my apps seems to point to just needing a "normal" rails-compatible gem.

**Would it be better to do this as a gem or as a Rails engine?**

If an engine is better, I'm not quite sure where to start.  From some of the guides I've read, it seems as though you create an engine on a fresh Rails application.  I'm also a little unclear on `full` vs. `mountable`, but I do know I'd like these models in their own namespace.

Finally, I would want these models usable in all my apps.  Engines *can* be packaged up as a gem, correct?  If so, then couldn't I just start off as a gem, instead of starting as an engine inside one particular app and then exporting the gem after the fact?

I'm quite confused, so any feedback is appreciated.  I've also never built a gem nor an engine before, so please forgive any stupidity in this area.

Comment: Why does not having anything other than models indicate you need an engine? In any case, which is "better" depends, and the rest is awfully broad. Might it make sense to start with something like http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html and ask very specific questions?

Comment: @DaveNewton:  Sorry, I meant that because it had *any* Rails "parts", it seems (to me) that it should be an engine.

Comment: Maybe, although I'm not sure why that'd be. If it's a Gem you can use it outside of Rails as well (e.g., command line util etc) so I tend towards that.

Comment: @DaveNewton:  Well, all the guides I've seen allude to "Reusable Rails stuff → use an engine".  These are specifically ActiveRecord models, so it doesn't make sense (for me) to use them outside of Rails.

Comment: I suppose, but there are lots of ActiveXxx stuff you can use outside of a Rails app.

Answer (score 4):

Engines aren't actually that magical, although it's easy to get that impression. At their simplest, an "engine" is a just subclass of `Rails::Engine`. As soon as it gets loaded by your Rails app (e.g. `require 'yourgem/engine`), the methods in your engine execute and hook up your engine to the Rails application (including magically appending a bunch of paths inside your engine to the applications' load paths, which is how your engine's models and controllers get loaded into your app).

Now, if you've tried reading [Getting Started With Rails Engines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html), you're probably thinking you can't create an engine unless you use the Rails generators, and stick to the Rails conventions, and all that. But all that is optional! I personally recommend creating a normal gem and turning it into an engine, largely just by reading the [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html), which are much more down-to-earth. Even the recommended pattern of having an `app` folder in your gem, to hold your models and controllers or whatnot, can be overridden (see the `Paths` section in the API docs).

So in your case, where you want your engine to just contain models, I'd suggest a gem layout like so:

```
yourgem/
  app/
    models/
      yourgem/
        your_thing.rb
  db/
    migrate/
      20160413010101_create_models.rb
  lib/
    yourgem/
      engine.rb
      version.rb
    yourgem.rb
  yourgem.gemspec
```

Your engine.rb can be pretty simple:

```
# lib/yourgem/engine.rb
module YourGem
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace YourGem # this is generally recommended

    # no other special configuration needed. But maybe you want
    # an initializer to be added to the app? Easy!
    initializer 'yourgem.boot_stuff_up' do
      YourGem.boot_something_up!
    end
  end
end
```

And your migration and models will look normal (though remember your model has to be scoped under your gem name, to avoid conflicts with whatever app may use this engine).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Well, you've explained engines a little more, but my original question remains unanswered:  Which is the better way to do what I need to do?  Also (maybe you missed), I don't have migrations; only models.

Comment: @istrasci: either way, you'll need to create a gem. Now, are your models subclasses of ActiveRecord::Base, or just plain-old-Ruby-objects? If the latter, forget all about engines. If the former, I'd suggest using an engine just to make the dependency on Rails explicit (and allow you to hook into, say, initializers or generators).

Comment: They are subclasses of ActiveRecord::Base.  So if I make an engine in one of my existing apps, how then do I "compile" this engine into a gem that my other apps can use?

Comment: I would recommend manually extracting it. By which I mean, create your gem (the `bundler init` command makes this easy; you should do it in your root workspace directory, not in any of your apps), create a folder structure like I posted above (without the migrations folder, since you don't need any), and move your models out of your app and into that gems' `app/models/myengine` folder. Since you're namespacing the models, remember to rename them all from `MyModel` to `MyEngine::MyModel`. Then, add that gem to your app's Gemfile, and update references to those models to reflect the namespacing.

Comment: If you've never made a gem before, it might be worth the exercise to create a simple gem to learn how gemspecs and rubygems work, before you add engines into the mix.